# Off-topic chats in SO Chat Rooms

Tags: discussion, chat

I just noticed that there is a lot of off-topic talk going on in many rooms which is beyond the intention of those rooms. For example the SOCVR should only accept close (reopen, etc etc) requests and all the other chatty messages should be avoided. Likewise, in the Android room only discussion about Android development should go on IMHO. Same applies for all the other rooms.

This will make the rooms more organised and it will feel more comfortable when we open a chat room and there is only room-related discussion going on. If this is followed, then there must be a separate room where all other chats can be done.

---

Should chat rooms be dedicated to a specific topic? If so, should there be a single room dedicated to all off-topic talk on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Frankly, I think you misunderstand the purpose of chat...there's no specific reason why chat between participants *has* to be on-topic for the source of the room...that would be incredibly boring. An "off-topic for everything" chat seems **particularly** pointless and confusing.

Comment: From the [FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq): "This site is an extension of Stack Overflow, so discussion should more or less revolve around the same topics you'd find at Stack Overflow". Making an chat that allows all type of discussions doesn't seem to be covered.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, that sounds like confusing, but if you go through some rooms, then you'll find that there is a lot of messages which are just not related to the room. I just want to make them more clean which will look cool

Comment: @BDL, Thanks, but any idea where this question might be appropriate?

Comment: ..and that's the beauty of chat. The participants in one room with similar interests can talk to each other **in the privacy of their own room** not try to be heard over a giant off-topic crowd all talking at the same time.

Comment: @Zlytherin: This is a citation from the **Chat** faq. The question here is not the problem, but a chatroom that is not restricted at all is against what the FAQ state.

Comment: @Paulie_D just imagine yourself when you open SOCVR, and there are only requests in the whole room. How cool will that look. I mean then the closing process will get boosted, as some unseen important requests will not be buried.

Comment: Chat rooms are governed by room owners, and in no way official. If you want to create your own SOCVR or Android room without off-topic chat, feel free, no-one's stopping you. But there's a good chance no-one will use them either because they like the off-topic chat. Also, we already have a chat room dedicated to off-topic chat, [The Ministry of Silly Hats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92764/the-ministry-of-silly-hats)

Comment: @ErikA Ahh, I didn't know about The Ministry of Silly Hats!

Comment: I first encountered SOCVR about a year ago and stayed because of the great people there - ROs included. If it was just wall to wall cv-pls requests it would bore me to tears. That said, I do wish the Ministry was busier as it feels a bit rude to fill SOCVR with off topic chat (I plead guilty of that on occasion).

Comment: @StephenKennedy Exactly, Either the ministry or the order, my whole point is to draw attention to at least one chat room, where we can just sit and chill. And also to make other rooms more organised.

Comment: Well we can't force people to the Ministry and SOCVR has both excellent ROs and members who are not afraid to speak to their minds, so if the chat gets too much we'll be asked to take it elsewhere (I have seen this happen). Therefore, I see no problem with the status quo. I do however see a problem with taking away the social aspect of SOCVR https://socvr.org/tour - moderating and reviewing can be a lonely business and the chat room helps alleviate that. (And so does SOBotics which has an equally awesome crowd of regulars).

Comment: To add to @Paulie_D 's comment, it seems to me that chat rooms are as much about making friends with people who are interested in the same topic as you as they are about the topic. So, your proposal gets a big fat downvote from me - but good luck with your new room.

Comment: *making friends with people who are interested in the same topic*. Agreed with this. Didn't consider that before!

Comment: @Zlytherin As someone who sits in SOCVR I don't want to sit in a room of people to just *"sit and chill"*, I want to sit in a room of *like minded people* where we can both work *and* chill. If I wanted to just chill I wouldn't be on SO.

Comment: @Zlytherin, terrible english let me rephrase. You noticed many room had off topics talk. You notice almost all rooms has off topics talk(in fact only bot's romm stay clear from off topics, most of the time). You notice that every one was doing it. 10k+ users, curators, meta-folks. And something still label it at off topics, must be avoid, need it's own room.

Comment: I think, long and very offtopic communication is not okay, not even on the chats.

Comment: @Closers I don't really understand why this got closed. As far as I can see the OP does seek input and discussion, and responds to the ideas brought in by others.

Comment: @peterh, Let the human have casual talk. I remember a time where SO user had the right to have casual talk. Even long off topics about natural disaster, the loosing of a relative, a car accident, domestic violence, the fact that the cat vomit on the keyboard, play on work and make bad pun for 3 hour strait because one user misstyped some basic word, where every on topic word were replace by salade word. It's ok for a community to let some kind of Freedom. I disagree with you.

Comment: @xdtTransform But how? You're here only for 1 year, aren't you?

Comment: @Zlytherin To be fair, you've only been here for 1yr2mo, so that's not something you can judge ;) Everyone is entitled to their opinion

Comment: @NickA Yes I cannot. But this guy is not making any sense in any of his comments here. *Let the human have casual talk* what does that mean? And *SO user had the right to have casual talk*? They still have that right

Comment: @Zlytherin Aha, but that's different reasoning, not related to just having been on the site a short time, I was merely suggesting you rephrase your question to them

Comment: Or *I's merely* ?

Comment: @ErikA to me this question reads like an ad for their new room. "I noticed something in the other rooms, I didn't like it, so I create my own room". Yes, the OP responds in comments, but the **question itself** as it stands does not seek input nor discussion. If the OP wants to have a discussion/does seek input, they'll need to rephrase the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Adriaan Ah, that's not how I read it, but I can understand it. I thought the discussion was a _should we ban all off-topic chat except in rooms dedicated to off-topic chat?_ and got an overwhelming __God no!__ expressed in downvotes.

Comment: @xdtTransform I fully agree with you! I said, only long and very offtopic talks shouldn't be allowed on the chat. I also think, it would be better to some other with them than deletion. For example, if the SE had a more friendly stance, I think they could move that "order of the phoenix" into the chatrooms of the sci-fi SE.

Comment: @peterh: If the room (owners) specifically allow(s) off-topic chat, then what's the problem?

Comment: @Cerbrus I think, that is obviously a special case where practically everything should be allowed. (Or, what is not, not even that on topicality reason). But, the general case, where an SO chatroom is filled with fantasy talks, I think the correct thing to is a migration to the correct site chat.

Comment: @peterh It's clear that you think it should be moved, but ___why___ should it be moved if the room allows off-topic chat?

Comment: @Cerbrus It is clear that you've read in my previous comment only the part what you can criticize. Read the whole comment, then we can continue.

Comment: Way to assume ill intentions, @peterh. Maybe you just weren't clear. If the room doesn't allow off-topic discussion, they have the tools to take care of it already, so there's still no reason to change anything about how chat works.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, it is agreeable. Except that I prefer migration to deletion.

Comment: Room owners can't delete chat messages, @peterh. It's standard practice to move off-topic discussion or other unwanted messages to a "trash" chatroom. So they're not deleted...

Comment: It is a *chat room*, and you're surprised that there's off-topic....wait for it.... *chatter*? Next you'll be telling us that water is wet, and Twitter is full of cranks with uninformed and irrelevant opinions.

Comment: @CodyGray This may be a bit too... chatty... but water is not wet, it makes things wet.

Comment: @Tyler The word you're looking for there is "pedantic". If you define "water" as "a single molecule of H2O", then, no, you are technically correct, it is not wet. However, once you have multiple molecules, then you get a liquid, and that liquid is completely saturated with liquid, and it is therefore wet. Water molecules are also strongly polar, which means they attract other water molecules, and neighboring water molecules interact with each other via hydrogen bonding, so you definitely have something that is saturated with liquid (i.e., wet). In other words, water wets itself.

Comment: @CodyGray No I was making a joke about chattiness being a problem, but your comment is a great example of pedantry :-D

Comment: _"that liquid is completely saturated with liquid"_ I gotta use that some time, somewhere xD

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> For example the SOCVR should only accept close (reopen, etc etc) requests and all the other chatty messages should be avoided.

I checked our [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq) and I haven't yet added any rules that prohibits chatter.

Under the heading [How does the room work?](https://socvr.org/faq#how-does-the-room-work) you'll find this paragraph:

> There are no obligations. We can't force you to do anything, and we don't want to either. The first purpose of the chat room is to have company as you go through the queue. Having a group beside you as you take on the queue really helps morale. We are also here to help with questions about what to do. Not sure what to do with a post? Post a link and we will take a look at it.

Similar wording is found in our [tour](https://socvr.org/tour).

From the start SOCVR was never meant to be an extra moderation queue. To have the expectation that we only should have moderation requests would be a huge deviation from my vision that I had and still have for that room.

There have been cases that the off-topic chatter became to much in which case RO's move SOCVR dicussions to [The Ministry of Silly hats](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92764/the-ministry-of-silly-hats).

If your concern is that open *-pls requests get burried in the transcript I suggest to go over [the tools page](https://socvr.org/tools/userscripts) where you'll find the [Unclosed Request Review Script](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/UnclosedRequestReview.user.js) that specifically deals with that issue.

That said, we're not a democracy but we, the RO team, do tend to listen to our regulars. Everyone is free to bring-up [topics](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/room-meeting-topics/issues) for a [roommeeting](https://socvr.org/room-info/room-meetings/info) which are then discussed and we try to reach a consensus that gets reflected in an updated FAQ. To see if your proposal gets any traction I posted a [new topic](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/room-meeting-topics/issues/25) with regard to your concern and I'll put it on the agenda for the next meeting.

Answer (score 37):

Room owners are very capable of moderating what kind of discussion is acceptable in their rooms.

Some rooms are more lenient in what is acceptable to talk about, some rooms are more strict. That's different per room, and decided on a room-by-room basis, by the room's owners.

There is no need for another "Off-topic" chatroom to police off-topic talk.